# Open Python Sub-Interpreter to Avoid Interpreter Crash?

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, interpreter

I'm using PythonWin, and a certain API function causes my interpreter to crash. I do not have ability to change the API, so I just have to deal with the crash. Is there a way to open a sub-interpreter in PythonWin, run the API through that, and let the sub-interpreter crash out, without taking the outer interpreter with it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahah!

I can create a windows batch file that runs a python script with the malfunctioning API. I then call that batch file from the original python interpreter. The sub-process runs the API and then crashes out, but the outer interpreter can still continue!

My batch file looks like this:

```
"C:\Python27\python.exe" "C:\\...\\crashing_code.py" > TestOut.txt
echo Done Batch Script
```

And the outer interpreter runs the following code to execute the batch file:

```
from subprocess import Popen
p = Popen(batch_filename.bat, cwd="C:\\...")
```

Works like a charm.